# createobject not found under windows 10

Tags: vbscript

The following VBS statement worked on previous Windows versions but not under Windows 10 where it provides error "The system can't find the file specified" -

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "c:\users\" & User & "\dropbox\bctrak\bct1.bat",0,True
```

It looks like CreateObject isn't being found under the default Windows 10 libs.

Any ideas on how to specify where and how to find it.  The whole script is only about 30 lines so I can post that if it helps.

Thanks,

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The system can't find the file specified" is caused by the .Run method:

```
type 33387109.vbs
Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
iRet = oWSH.Run("c:\nix.exe")

cscript 33387109.vbs
..\33387109.vbs(2, 1) (null): The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So check the file spec of your .bat.

Comment: I can't see anything that may cause this!!   Why would this only happen with the change to Windows 10 ?

Comment: I solved the issue myself, by using some MSG boxes to show the results of earlier code and for some reason earlier Instr code didn't extract string details as happened previously.  Now all is fixed.

Comment: A bit more, the code as shown was fine, but the content of the User variable was invalid so the command couldn't be run.  It may also not be limited to Windows 10, so users beware.  Thanks for the response Ekkehard.